# How to access object properties using variable containing underscore

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to access object properties using variable containing underscore however, its giving error `Uncaught ReferenceError: topic_ is not defined`. I did look into this question for solution [Dynamically access object property using variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4244896/dynamically-access-object-property-using-variable) however it didn't work.

```
var topics_page_no = {
    topic_1: [2,3,4],
    topic_2: [5,6,7]
}

/* Navigate to particular topic's first page based on selection */
$(document).on('click', '.topic-menu-dropdown-item', function(){
    var topic_id = $(this).data('topic-id');
    console.log(topics_page_no.topic_[topic_id][0] + ".html");
});
```

**Expected output:** `2.html / 5.html`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can try  **[Bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors)** like this:

```
 /* Navigate to particular topic's first page based on selection */
$(document).on('click', '.topic-menu-dropdown-item', function () {
    var topic_id = $(this).data('topic-id');
    console.log(topics_page_no["topic_" + [topic_id]][0] + ".html");
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to use brackets notation and a string giving the **full** variable  name. `topics_page_no.topic_[topic_id]` is looking up a property on `topics_page_no` called `topic_` and then trying to look up a property on *that* which matches the `topic_id`. Instead, you want to combine `"topic_"` with `topic_id` to form the complete name of the property to look up on `topics_page_no`:

So:

```
var topic_id = $(this).data('topic-id');
console.log(topics_page_no["topic_" + topic_id][0] + ".html");
// -----------------------^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use Bracket notation like this:

```
/* Navigate to particular topic's first page based on selection */
$(document).on('click', '.topic-menu-dropdown-item', function () {
   var topic_id = $(this).data('topic-id');
   console.log(topics_page_no["topic_" + [topic_id]][0] + ".html");
});
```